# Flutter local notification custom sound doesn't work (path issue)

Tags: flutter, notifications

I want setting up a custom sound for my local notification in the Android side. 
I created a raw folder in the res folder of Android project.
This is the part of my code which I put my alarm.mp3 file path in the notification.

```
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
                    new AndroidNotificationDetails(
                        "$id",
                        not.columnValue + not.deveui,
                        not.columnValue + not.deveui,
                        sound: "@raw/alarm",
                        importance: Importance.Max,
                        priority: Priority.High);
```

Actually it still sounds with the default system sound.
If I put `@raw/alarm.mp3`, I got the following exception: `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(INVALID_SOUND, The resource %s could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a raw resource to your Android head project., null)`

note : sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('alarm'), solved

Answer (score 26, accepted):

thanks for sunnyque for giving awesome solution, but here's how i implemented it into my fcm,

first : you have to set **"channel_id","playSound: true",
"sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('yourmp3files.mp3')"**:
[adding specific channel on flutter_local_notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LJ5k.png)

```
Future displayNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'you_can_name_it_whatever',
      'flutterfcm',
      'flutterfcm',
      playSound: true,
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('yourmp3files.mp3'),
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
```

then, add mp3 file into **res/raw/yourmp3files.mp3** [adding mp3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn7k7.png)

after that you need to add keep.xml inside res/raw/keep.xml to include yourmp3files.mp3 into build [keep.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlhMZ.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@raw/yourmp3files"
    />
```

your done, now you can test the fcm custom sound in your app, do

> uninstal last build

> flutter clean

> flutter pub get

> flutter build apk

> flutter run --release

tada , tell me if its work, hehe

i hope this help someone in the future

Comment: removing ".mp3" in RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound fixed my problem

Comment: I had the same error, and it got fixed by adding keep.xml, but there is still no sound with the notification (vibrate is working though). What could be the reason?

Comment: Is it possible to play sound files from this directory with Flutter?

Comment: removing .mp3 it's also worked for me
like this -> 
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('yourmp3files'),

Comment: Hey, I'm having a similar issue, could you provide a bit more information? Like how do you call the displayNotification method and if I need to make any changes to the MainActivity.kt 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, custom notifications sound works perfectly fine in debug mode without "keep.xml".

Do we have to add the ".mp3" extension while adding the path to the file in "keep.xml"?

Comment: You have saved my day and dear sir, I tip my hat to you

Comment: removing .mp3 fixed my issue too, thanks, everyone!
for iOS though where to add the file?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to put '@raw/' to path, plugin is already taking sounds from it (according to plugin source: FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java function retrieveSoundResourceUri) so remove it.

also check that sound file is included in build, ex. by creating keep.xml in raw folder with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/*,@raw/alarm" />
```

that might help

Comment: Your tip about including the keep.xml just resolved all the issues I've been facing. Thanks!

Comment: @Synnyque Is it possible to play sound files from this directory with an audio player?

Answer (score 4):

To complete previous useful helps, don't forget to change your channel id if your app was created before your sound modification, I don't know why but with the existing channel, the sound is not taken into account (few hours lost for this, hope it helps others)

Comment: This answer will save many of us <3