# Flutter: local notifications custom sound doesn't work

Tags: flutter, android-notifications

I'm trying to play my own custom sound for my notifications. But on my android emulator, it just plays the default sound and on my own device, it doesn't even make a sound. 
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59931642/11979688) but it didn't help me.

```dart
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
await _notifications.initialize(initializationSettings);
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails('test_channel', 'test', '', playSound: true, sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('my_sound'));
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
await _notifications.show(0, 'test', 'this is a test', platformChannelSpecifics);
```

I don't get any errors. My file is in android/app/src/main/res/raw/my_sound.mp3

Comment: had you solved the issue???

Comment: @JakesMD any update for your issue?

Comment: No sorry. I abandoned the project a long time ago.

Answer (score 20):

Simple fix! You have to uninstall and reinstall the app completely instead of just updating it. The notification settings from your first install will persist, so if it was once set to default sound, that will persist if you don't change the channel id. More info [here](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/563#issuecomment-609614118)

Comment: I uninstalled and installed again and changed channel id also. It works in emulator but in real device it play default sound. What can be the error?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [doc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#custom-notification-icons-and-sounds):
"For Android 8.0 or newer, this (sound) is tied to the specified channel and cannot
be changed after the channel has been created for the first time."

So, either create a separate channel or just uninstall the application to delete the notification channel and reinstall it.

Comment: Can you share the  link?

Comment: @3nomis https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#custom-notification-icons-and-sounds

Comment: How about deleting the channel then creating it again?